# Galaxy Gear not recognised in sdb and Odin so I cant downgrade

Tags: android, tizen

I need help downgrading my recently bought Samsung Galaxy Gear (original) from eBay which came with Tizen pre-installed. Already I have been looking around the internet for about 3 days now and I cant find the answer, No matter what my Galaxy Gear is not appearing in either Odin or sdb I have enabled USB debugging
Please respond,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will fix problems related to any **samsung(Tizen/android/gear)** device not getting recognised in **SDB shell or ODIN or My Computer**.

You need to have **Samsung USB driver** installed on your system then only it will be recognised by ODIN or SDB.

1. **Download** it from here http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000117
2. **Extract** it and **install** the executable.

Now, connect your device and check below in taskbar a small popup with **Installing devicer driver** will be shown. After that system will automatically perform driver software installation for connected device.

For more info check here http://samsung.tizenforum.com/?topic=76.0

Comment: Thanks, But I just tried that and it installed the driver but after I install that its still not recognised in Odin or sdb and not even Kies 3 is there somthing I might need to do on the device?